# How to import csv with same filename to data frame, apply some program, then merge?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two types of file with same file name in two different folder, contains different information that I need to preprocess then merge. I've been doing it manually using:

```
a = './location/ID01.csv'

df1 = pd.read_csv(a)

# and rest of codes to preprocess a
```

and for other file

```
b = './log/ID01.csv'

df2 = pd.read_csv(b)

# and rest of codes to preprocess b
```

then I manually merge each using

```
new_df = df2.merge(df1, on=['hour'], how='outer')
new_df.to_csv('merged.csv')
```

but of course it is time consuming. How can I do it in a loop so that all files in both folder can be processed in one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
import os
import pandas as pd


files_in_log = set(os.listdir('log'))
files_in_location = set(os.listdir('location'))
os.mkdir('results')
for filename in files_in_log & files_in_location:
    df1 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join('log', filename))    
    df2 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join('location', filename))    
    new_df = df2.merge(df1, on=['hour'], how='outer')    
    new_df.to_csv(os.path.join('results', filename))
```

Comment: in os.mkdir('results') should I change it to the dir where I wanted the result to be saved?

Comment: @npm Yes, that was my intent.

Comment: I keep getting the FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'result' error, with 'result' is the name of folder I'd like to keep the results on and it is on the same dir with other 2 folders. Any idea?

Comment: @npm If you have already created the folder, try removing the os.mkdir line.

Comment: it worked well until then I found this error ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed. Try engine='python'. Can you help?

Comment: Also this error  File b'log/.ipynb_checkpoints' does not exist not sure what did I do wrong